# laravel nova - how to make a self referential model with restriction

Tags: php, laravel, many-to-many, laravel-nova, self-reference

I have a laravel model based on the following table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('things', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->string('label');
        $table->foreignId('user_id')->nullable()->constrained('users');
    });
```

There is also a pivot table that makes this a many-to-many self-referential model.

```
  public function up()
  {
    Schema::create('thing_thing', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->id();
      $table->timestamps();
      $table->string('message')->nullable();
      $table->unsignedBigInteger('parent_id')->nullable();
      $table->unsignedBigInteger('child_id')->nullable();
      $table->unique(['parent_id', 'child_id']);
      $table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('things')->onDelete('cascade');
      $table->foreign('child_id')->references('id')->on('things')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
  }
```

When I create a Nova resource linked to this model, I would like to restrict the attaching of a `thing` to itself.  So a `thing` with `id = 1`, for example, would not show up in the selector for attachments for the thing with `id = 1`.  Here's my Nova resource:

```
  public function fields(Request $request)
  {
    return [
      ID::make(__('ID'), 'id')->sortable(),
      Text::make('label'),
      ID::make('user_id')->hideWhenUpdating()->hideWhenCreating(),
      BelongsToMany::make('Trees', 'trees'),
      BelongsToMany::make('Things', 'childOf'),
      BelongsToMany::make('Things', 'parentOf')
    ];
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this through the `App\Nova\Ressource`'s `relatableQuery` method. Simply override the method in your nova resource:

```php
class Thing extends Resource {

    // ...

    public static function relatableQuery(NovaRequest $request, $query)
    {
        // Make sure you only apply the filter to the things-things relatable query
        if( $request->route('resource') === 'things' ) {
            $currentId = $request->route('resourceId');
            $query->where('id', '!=', $currentId);
        }
        return $query
    }
}
```

You can find the docs [here](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/resources/authorization.html#relatable-filtering)

In addition, you might want to make the column-combination of `parent_id` and `child_id` unique in your migration to further ensure uniqueness.